# Ruby on Rails - Trigger an event automatically on specific DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to trigger an event, specifically send out an email and update attributes on some models, on a specific DateTime (which is a column in one of my models).

I have searched around but have not really found any solutions to this.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Look into ruby scheduler, cron tasks, and things like this. If you are on a hosting site like heroku, they have it as an addon.

Comment: Something to clarify. Cron jobs can be run every 10mins, 1h , 1day... but cannot be every second. If you don't need second/minute level accuracy, that's fine. Otherwise(since I noticed your data type is DateTime, which contain seconds), you might need to consider something else. For example, delayed_job gem will allow you to enqueue a job to a queue and run at a certain timestamp.

Comment: you can use delayed_job gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a queueing solution along with a scheduler.

Queueing solution: Resque with Redis backend 
https://github.com/resque/resque

Scheduling solution : https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

```
Resque.enqueue_at(5.days.from_now, SomeJob)
```

You can schedule a job to run at a particular date. Combine this with the ability to setup a schedule.

Say you trigger the first job on Jan 1st and want it to run every 30 days.

You can use a queuing solution to send out email asynchronously : something like Resque with a Redis backend.